# Custom Circular Loading Indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Please look at this Sample Loading Indicator in Android, I want to make same in iOS.
[Loading Indicator in Android](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView)

can any one guide me ?
Thanks in advance

[At last got this demo which partially fits my requirement](https://github.com/misterwell/MMMaterialDesignSpinner)

[I will edit it to look like this](https://www.behance.net/gallery/18484593/Loader-App-(Gifs))

Comment: Being complete unaware about what is the concept or functionality is called, How can one start with trying, or one should be given at least a direction to go about his query, instead of down voting or  closing question.

This way new user may avoid asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

several types available in iOS  , customize yourself

1. [MRActivityIndicatorView](http://www.programering.com/a/MTOwcjNwATk.html)
2. [BTProgressHUD](https://github.com/nicwise/BTProgressHUD)
3. [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD).
4. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)
5. [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress)
6. [TYMActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/yimingtang/TYMActivityIndicatorView)
7. [UAProgressView](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAProgressView)
8. [FFCircularProgressView](https://github.com/elbryan/FFCircularProgressView)
9. [MMMaterialDesignSpinner](https://github.com/misterwell/MMMaterialDesignSpinner)
10. [UCZProgressView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UCZProgressView)

Comment: can you give the proper reason for down voting , if it is eligible I remove my answer

Comment: I have not down voted, But I want to mention that you have not looked at my requirement properly, anyways thanks for attempting.

Comment: I recommend to you SVProgressHUD, it will easy to handle and it is same as you need

Comment: This is the useful links.From that you have to customize your coding.So don't down vote.

Comment: @user3182143 , I have not down voted,  though  SVProgressHud is not suitable to my requirements,
I have found this Demon which exactly fit into my requirement

https://github.com/misterwell/MMMaterialDesignSpinner

Comment: Ya nice bro I am not seen in before , I add this one also in the answer , it is helpful for anyone in future , great day brother